# Can I get how many credit left in aws billing by aws cli?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, aws-billing

Is it possible to get "Total amount remaining" or "Amount remaining" and "Expiration date" by aws cli (or another)?
I can't find any commands to do it in [`aws ce` commands.](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/ce/index.html).

For example, this below is my "AWS Billing > Credits".

[image]

I want to get "$74.79" or "09/30/2024 - $24.79, 11/30/2023 - $50.00" by "aws blarblar ~~" commands in terminal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Curiously, AWS does not provide an API for the billing page, so the remaining credit information cannot be viewed through the cli.